# How to store and use existing information (in Excel) in my app with SQLite?

Tags: android, excel, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have a big Excel spreadsheet with multiple columns and rows that I'd like to somehow use in my app to look up certain information. How would I go about converting this spreadsheet to an SQLite DB -> table?

I'm aware of this website (http://converttosqlite.com/) but for some reason when I try to use the database it produces in my app, there are no tables inside the database except android_metadata.

**TL;DR** what's the most common way of converting and using a bunch of data (initially stored in an Excel spreadsheet) in an Android application?

Answer (score 0):

The database produced by the conversion will not work because the Sqlite used in Android looks for a special table in the database order to read it.  You can read more about this [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

A couple of options to add the data are:

- To modify the converted database (as described in the link above) so that it can be opened and read by the Android Sqlite functions
- To export the Excel data to a CSV file, then parse and insert that data into a new database from within your App.